# I need to program in Matlab do loops

Tags: matlab

I have four parameters Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 and I want to increase the parameters sequentiality 0.05
I mean I want to start the four parameters with the value 0.1, then increase Q1 by 0.05 and keep the others as it 0.1. then keep Q1=0.15, increase the second one Q2  0.05  a

Comment: this sounds like homework to me. what have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to generate all possible tuples from the four parameters, where each can go from `0.1` to some higher value (I am using `0.2`) in `0.05` increases. If this is the case, you can use the [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html) function:

```
[q1,q2,q3,q4] = ndgrid(0.1:0.05:0.2);
params = [q1(:) q2(:) q3(:) q4(:)]
```

The result as rows:

```
params =
          0.1          0.1          0.1          0.1
         0.15          0.1          0.1          0.1
          0.2          0.1          0.1          0.1
          0.1         0.15          0.1          0.1
         0.15         0.15          0.1          0.1
          0.2         0.15          0.1          0.1
          0.1          0.2          0.1          0.1
         0.15          0.2          0.1          0.1
          0.2          0.2          0.1          0.1
          0.1          0.1         0.15          0.1
         0.15          0.1         0.15          0.1
          0.2          0.1         0.15          0.1
          0.1         0.15         0.15          0.1
         0.15         0.15         0.15          0.1
          0.2         0.15         0.15          0.1
          0.1          0.2         0.15          0.1
         0.15          0.2         0.15          0.1
          0.2          0.2         0.15          0.1
          0.1          0.1          0.2          0.1
         0.15          0.1          0.2          0.1
          0.2          0.1          0.2          0.1
          0.1         0.15          0.2          0.1
         0.15         0.15          0.2          0.1
          0.2         0.15          0.2          0.1
          0.1          0.2          0.2          0.1
         0.15          0.2          0.2          0.1
          0.2          0.2          0.2          0.1
          0.1          0.1          0.1         0.15
         0.15          0.1          0.1         0.15
          0.2          0.1          0.1         0.15
          0.1         0.15          0.1         0.15
         0.15         0.15          0.1         0.15
          0.2         0.15          0.1         0.15
          0.1          0.2          0.1         0.15
         0.15          0.2          0.1         0.15
          0.2          0.2          0.1         0.15
          0.1          0.1         0.15         0.15
         0.15          0.1         0.15         0.15
          0.2          0.1         0.15         0.15
          0.1         0.15         0.15         0.15
         0.15         0.15         0.15         0.15
          0.2         0.15         0.15         0.15
          0.1          0.2         0.15         0.15
         0.15          0.2         0.15         0.15
          0.2          0.2         0.15         0.15
          0.1          0.1          0.2         0.15
         0.15          0.1          0.2         0.15
          0.2          0.1          0.2         0.15
          0.1         0.15          0.2         0.15
         0.15         0.15          0.2         0.15
          0.2         0.15          0.2         0.15
          0.1          0.2          0.2         0.15
         0.15          0.2          0.2         0.15
          0.2          0.2          0.2         0.15
          0.1          0.1          0.1          0.2
         0.15          0.1          0.1          0.2
          0.2          0.1          0.1          0.2
          0.1         0.15          0.1          0.2
         0.15         0.15          0.1          0.2
          0.2         0.15          0.1          0.2
          0.1          0.2          0.1          0.2
         0.15          0.2          0.1          0.2
          0.2          0.2          0.1          0.2
          0.1          0.1         0.15          0.2
         0.15          0.1         0.15          0.2
          0.2          0.1         0.15          0.2
          0.1         0.15         0.15          0.2
         0.15         0.15         0.15          0.2
          0.2         0.15         0.15          0.2
          0.1          0.2         0.15          0.2
         0.15          0.2         0.15          0.2
          0.2          0.2         0.15          0.2
          0.1          0.1          0.2          0.2
         0.15          0.1          0.2          0.2
          0.2          0.1          0.2          0.2
          0.1         0.15          0.2          0.2
         0.15         0.15          0.2          0.2
          0.2         0.15          0.2          0.2
          0.1          0.2          0.2          0.2
         0.15          0.2          0.2          0.2
          0.2          0.2          0.2          0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to increase your four parameters one at a time? How about you use a simple modulus statement, like this:

```
for (int i  = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        Q1 += 0.05;
    } else if (i % 4 == 1) {
        Q2 += 0.05;
    } else if (i % 4 == 2) {
        Q3 += 0.05;
    } else {
        Q4 += 0.05;
    }
}
```

That way, after one loop you will have:

```
Q1 = 0.15
Q2 = 0.10
Q3 = 0.10
Q4 = 0.10
```

But after two, you have:

```
Q1 = 0.15
Q2 = 0.15
Q3 = 0.10
Q4 = 0.10
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Also, with Matlab without `for` loop and `if` statements:

```
n=4;
step=0.05;
base=floor((2:1/4:n));
q=base*step;
q1=q(4:end);
q2=q(3:end-1);
q3=q(2:end-2);
q4=q(1:end-3);
```

Which produces:

```
0.10    0.15    0.15    0.15    0.15    0.20
0.10    0.10    0.15    0.15    0.15    0.15
0.10    0.10    0.10    0.15    0.15    0.15
0.10    0.10    0.10    0.10    0.15    0.15
```